# Electron - sequalize 7 not recognize odbc npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, sequelize.js, odbc

I've installed sequalize 7 as a dependency of my electron app. I need to connect to an ibm i system, so I've followed the documentation and installed the odbc driver as explained, anyway everytime I run the `npm run electron:serve` command I will always get the error that is visible from the attached image.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a bug of sequelize v7 or if I need to do something after the installation of the odbc driver. Can anyone help me please?